# gRPC and gRPC-web backend not connecting though kubernetes nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, grpc-web

I have a gRPC server set up in AWS EKS, and use Nginx-Ingress-Controller with network load balancer , infornt of gRPC , Envoy is using , So it will come like that - NLB >> Ingress >> envoy >> gRPC
problem is when we make reqy=uist from bloomRPC , requist not landing into Envoy

**What you expected to happen:**
It should be connect requist from out side to grpc service and, need to use gRPC and gRPC-web with ssl, looking best solution for this.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):**
Spinup normail gRPC and grpc-web service , connect gRPC service using envoy , below conf i used to Envoy, and inginx-ingress-controller also I tryed using with nginx ingress controller nginx-ingress-controller:0.30.0 image, becoase of its will help to connect HTTP2 and gRPC with nginx ingress rule

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-http2: enabled
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
  name: tk-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - test.domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: test.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: envoy
            port:
              number: 80
```

Envoy - conf

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /dev/stdout
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8801 }
static_resources:
  # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/config/listener/v3/listener.proto#config-listener-v3-listener
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8803
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto#extensions-filters-network-http-connection-manager-v3-httpconnectionmanager
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                access_log:
                  # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/access_loggers/file/v3/file.proto
                  #
                  # You can also configure this extension with the qualified
                  # name envoy.access_loggers.http_grpc
                  # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/access_loggers/grpc/v3/als.proto
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                    typed_config:
                      # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/access_loggers/file/v3/file.proto#extensions-access-loggers-file-v3-fileaccesslog
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                      # Console output
                      path: /dev/stdout
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains:
                        - "test.domain.com"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: /
                            grpc:
                          route:
                            cluster: tkmicro
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        # custom-header-1 is just an example. the grpc-web
                        # repository was missing grpc-status-details-bin header
                        # which used in a richer error model.
                        # https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error/#richer-error-model
                        allow_headers: accept-language,accept-encoding,user-agent,referer,sec-fetch-mode,origin,access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,cache-control,pragma,connection,host,name,x-grpc-web,x-user-agent,grpc-timeout,content-type,channel,api-key,lang
                        expose_headers: grpc-status-details-bin,grpc-status,grpc-message,authorization
                        max_age: "1728000"
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    # This line is optional, but adds clarity to the configuration.
                    typed_config:
                      # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/grpc_web/v3/grpc_web.proto
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/cors/v3/cors.proto
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder.v3.GrpcJsonTranscoder
                      proto_descriptor: "/home/ubuntu/envoy/sync.pb"
                      ignore_unknown_query_parameters: true
                      services:
                        - "com.tk.system.sync.Synchronizer"
                      print_options:
                        add_whitespace: true
                        always_print_primitive_fields: true
                        always_print_enums_as_ints: true
                        preserve_proto_field_names: true
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/router/v3/router.proto
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                alpn_protocols: "h2"

  clusters:
    # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.15.0/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/cluster.proto#config-cluster-v3-cluster
    - name: tkmicro
      type: LOGICAL_DNS
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: tkmicro
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 172.20.120.201
                      port_value: 8081
      http2_protocol_options: {} # Force HTTP/2
```

Anything else we need to know?:
from bloomRPC getting this error

```
"error": "14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server"
```

Environment:
Kubernetes version (use kubectl version): GitVersion:"v1.21.1"
Cloud provider or hardware configuration: AWS -EKS

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried many combinations but I got it working with kreya